# Why is there a difference in the size of pointer to the struct variable when used with and without * operator in the sizeof() function?

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *node1;

node1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

node1->data = 5;
node1->next = NULL;

cout<<"node data value "<<node1->data<<endl;

int *vara;

cout<<"size of struct node pointer with * "<<sizeof(*node1)<<endl; // size is 8
cout<<"size of struct node pointer without * "<<sizeof(node1)<<endl; // size is 4
cout<<"size of integer pointer variable with * "<<sizeof(*vara)<<endl; // size is 4
cout<<"size of integer pointer variable with * "<<sizeof(*vara)<<endl; // size is 4 in this case as well

}
```

Why is there some difference in the size when used with `*` operator and without `*` operator for a pointer pointing to a struct variable ?

Executed the above code in CodeBlocks, Language C++.

Comment: `*node1` is not a pointer, it has a type of `struct node` (since you dereferenced it with `*`, therefore you are not comparing the sizes of pointers, but size of a pointer to size of a struct, which is apples to oranges kind of comparison.

Comment: _"If we go by your logic, then I think no question can be asked on C++"_ The logic wasn't "no question can be asked on C++". It was "no question should be asked on C++ if it can be easily self-answered by simply reading an introductory tutorial or book". We're not here to teach the basics to every 5,000 new C++ visitors each day :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I get the point. Will follow your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** because `node1` is a pointer and `*node1` is a `node`, and these have different sizes.

---

**Longer answer:**

Let's examine the type of each of the expressions you are passing to the `sizeof` operator:

1. `*node1` has type `node`, which consists of an `int` and a `node*`, both of which has size 4 bytes on your platform, hence making the total size 8 bytes.
2. `node1` has type `node*`, which is *a pointer*. On your platform, pointers are 4 bytes long.
3. `*vara` has type `int`, which is *an integer*. On your platform, integers are 4 bytes long.
4. `vara` has type `int*`, which is *a pointer*. On your platform, pointers are 4 bytes long.

Comment: Thank you for a very clear answer ! Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @livetolearn: No problem. Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The first `sizeof` returns the size of the struct (the size of an `int` + the size of a pointer) , the second one the size of a *pointer* to a struct (4 bytes on your machine) the third one the size of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It is because a pointer, in this case, has the same size (4 bytes) than an integer, but your `node` structure's size is 8 bytes.
When you ask for `sizeof(a)` when `a` is a pointer, you ask for the size of the pointer. When you ask for `sizeof(*a)`, you ask for the size of what is pointed by `a`.

Comment: _"a pointer has the same size (4 bytes) than an integer,"_ [Are you sure?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/493549450f8ccaa1)

Comment: It depends on the machine, but I meant in this case.

Comment: Let's be absolutely clear to avoid spreading misconceptions :)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there some difference in the size when used with "" operator and without "" operator for a pointer pointing to a struct variable ?

Because they are different types. In this declaration:

```
node *ptr;
```

`ptr` has type `pointer to node`, while `*ptr` has type `node`. In your third and forth example looks like you wanted to compare `int` vs `int *`. The fact that you get the same size for `int *` and `int` is just a coincidence and happened to be the same on your platform. You cannot either rely on that nor deduce any rules from that fact.